# Move div and its content before and after a divider to a new container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to move some html before a div to a new div and after a div 
to a new div .

For eg

```
<div><div>DATA</div></div>     

<div><div>DIVIDER</div></div> 

<div><div>DATA</div></div>
```

I want to detect the DIVIDER (separator) and move all the main data div's and inner div above that to a new container and all the main data div's and inner div to a new container . I have attached my progress so far . But it seems to move the above div's and the data again to the below one's to a new div .

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
 jQuery("#layout_post").append("<div class='mi-cst-pg '></div>");
 jQuery("#layout_post").append("<div class='mi-cst-pg mi-after'></div>");
 //var $e = jQuery("<div>", {id: "newDiv1", name: 'test', class: "aClass"});
   jQuery(".MiniMax_Separator").parents(".mirow-fr").prevAll(".mirow-fr").appendTo(".mi-cst-pg");
  jQuery(".MiniMax_Separator").parents(".mirow-fr").nextAll(".mirow-fr").appendTo(".mi-after");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w3eden" id="layout_post"><div class="mirow-fr minimax_content_area row " id="row_55445d450d502" style="margin:px px px px;padding:px px px px;"> 

        <div class="gridt col-md-12 minimax_column" id="column_1_55445d450d502">
                <div class="minimax_module wow  MiniMax_RichText  animated" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1s"><p><a href="/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/838480010005.jpglt_.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-193" src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/838480010005.jpglt_.jpg" alt="838480010005.jpglt" width="470" height="311"></a></p></div>
                    </div>
 
    
  
 

 <div style="clear: both;"></div></div><div class="mirow-fr minimax_content_area row " id="row_5544b2d36bee4" style="margin:px px px px;padding:px px px px;"> 

        <div class="gridt col-md-12 minimax_column" id="column_1_5544b2d36bee4">
                <div class="minimax_module wow  MiniMax_Separator  animated" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1s"><div style="margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:15px; border-top:1px solid "><!--nextpage--></div></div>
                    </div>
 
    
  
 

 <div style="clear: both;"></div></div><div class="mirow-fr minimax_content_area row " id="row_55445dde7d66d" style="margin:px px px px;padding:px px px px;"> 

        <div class="gridt col-md-5 minimax_column" id="column_1_55445dde7d66d">
                <div class="minimax_module wow  MiniMax_RichText  animated" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1s"><p><a href="/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/anigif_enhanced-buzz-12180-1355761194-14.gif"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-194" src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/anigif_enhanced-buzz-12180-1355761194-14.gif" alt="anigif_enhanced-buzz-12180-1355761194-14" width="250" height="188"></a></p></div>
                    </div>
 
    
 

        <div class="gridt col-md-7 minimax_column" id="column_2_55445dde7d66d">
                
                    </div>
 

  
 

 <div style="clear: both;"></div></div><div class="mi-cst-pg "></div><div class="mi-cst-pg mi-after"></div></div>
```

Comment: give an example like how it will look like after the change. this is too confusing `move all the main data div's and inner div above that to a new container and all the main data div's and inner div to a new container `

Comment: @erkaner Thank you for your reply . I have attached my progress but i understand your point . Thre result would be like . <div class="new-cont"><div class="old-cont">old data</div></div>